# JSF1070: Invalid query string in navigation outcome agendamentoGeralRelatorioPauta.faces?

Tags: jsf, navigation, query-string

Using Tomcat 8.0.24 or WildFly 9.0
Also using PrimeFaces 5.2 and JSF 2.2.12
I keep getting error JSF

> 20:17:47,639 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default
>   task-28) JSF1070: Seqüência de consulta inválida no resultado da
>   navegação agendamentoGeralRelatorioPauta.faces?

Looks like it corresponds in English to,

> jsf.navigation_invalid_query_string=JSF1070: "Invalid query string in
>   navigation outcome {0}"

My project works normal but my logs are poluted by thousands of lines with this kind information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation outcome `agendamentoGeralRelatorioPauta.faces?` has an empty query string. The `?` is the query string separator character. It's expected that any character sequence thereafter represents the query string. However, if no one is found, then this warning will be displayed to warn the developer about a possible mistake. The developer may have forgotten to specify the actual query string, or the developer may have forgotten to remove the `?`.

In your specific case, it seems that you just forgot to remove the `?`. Removing it should make the warning disappear.